# Array List Sort by Boolean then by Date JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typescript, sorting

> I am adding new item to the list dynamically and sorting it after
> based on the status first and then by date. working code

**I want the list to show false status items with latest date to show first by desc then the true value items by the date desc whenever I add a new item to the list**

```
added item ={"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:43:01.377Z","Title":"test6"}
```

**Unordered list:-**

```
var itemlist = [{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:28:23.841Z","Title":"test5"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:03:12.736Z","Title":"test4"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:02:01.901Z","Title":"test3"},{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T06:46:34.614Z","Title":"test2"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-22T14:33:41.351Z","Title":"test1"},{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-16T06:28:41.568Z","Title":"Test0"}];
```

**Expected Result:-**

```
var itemlist = [{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:43:01.377Z","Title":"test6"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:03:12.736Z","Title":"test4"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:02:01.901Z","Title":"test3"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-22T14:33:41.351Z","Title":"test1"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:28:23.841Z","Title":"test5"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T06:46:34.614Z","Title":"test2"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-16T06:28:41.568Z","Title":"Test0"}];
```

**Obtained result:-**

```
var itemlist = [{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:03:12.736Z","Title":"test4"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:02:01.901Z","Title":"test3"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-22T14:33:41.351Z","Title":"test1"},{
    "Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:43:01.377Z","Title":"test6"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:28:23.841Z","Title":"test5"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T06:46:34.614Z","Title":"test2"},{
    "Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-16T06:28:41.568Z","Title":"Test0"}];
```

**used method:-**

```
var res=itemlist.sort(
   (a, b) => (a.Status === b.Status ) ? 
      0 : (a.Status ? 1 : -1 || +new Date(b.Date)- +new Date(a.Date)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sort by

- `Status` with delta of value ascending, and
- `Date` as string descending.

```js
var itemlist = [{ Status: true, Date: "2021-07-23T07:28:23.841Z", Title: "test5" }, { Status: false, Date: "2021-07-23T07:03:12.736Z", Title: "test4" }, { Status: false, Date: "2021-07-23T07:02:01.901Z", Title: "test3" }, { Status: true, Date: "2021-07-23T06:46:34.614Z", Title: "test2" }, { Status: false, Date: "2021-07-22T14:33:41.351Z", Title: "test1" }, { Status: true, Date: "2021-07-16T06:28:41.568Z", Title: "Test0" }, { Status: false, Date: "2021-07-23T07:43:01.377Z", Title: "test6" }];

itemlist.sort((a, b) => a.Status - b.Status || b.Date.localeCompare(a.Date));

console.log(itemlist);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Works fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logical OR operator in the `sort` callback.

```js
var itemlist = [{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:28:23.841Z","Title":"test5"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:03:12.736Z","Title":"test4"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-23T07:02:01.901Z","Title":"test3"},{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-23T06:46:34.614Z","Title":"test2"},{
"Status":false,"Date":"2021-07-22T14:33:41.351Z","Title":"test1"},{
"Status":true,"Date":"2021-07-16T06:28:41.568Z","Title":"Test0"}];
itemlist.sort((a,b) => a.Status - b.Status || new Date(b.Date) - new Date(a.Date))
console.log(itemlist);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Unordered list:-` and `Expected Result:-` don't have the same number of elements in your example data. When you ask for help try getting the example data right.

**Solution:**

```
var compareFn = (a, b) => {
    if (a.Status !== b.Status) {
        return a.Status ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return new Date(b.Date) < new Date(a.Date) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

var res=itemlist.sort(compareFn);
```

**Explanation:**

if `.Status` doesn't match we want the element with false first, else if `.Status` matches we want to compare dates.